# Use a variable's value in a sed command

Tags: bash, variables, sed, escaping

I can't seem to use a variable in a sed command, for example:

```
sed "24s/.*/"$ct_tname"/" file1.sas > file2.sas
```

I want `$ct_tname` the variable, not literally `$ct_tname`, which is what I keep getting.

Anybody know how to get this to work?

The problem is actually more complex and I omitted some information.

```
ct_fname="%let outputfile="/user/ct_"$1".csv";"
```

Here, `$1` is the argument passed in at the start of my bash script (sed is being run inside a bash script).

This doesn't run successfully, but it does run if I replace `ct_fname` with

```
ct_fname="%let table=ct_$1;"
```

Is there a way to get the first `ct_fname` to be passed successfully?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you need to use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`). 
single quotes pass their content literally, without translating variables (expansion).

try

```
sed "24s/.*/\"$ct_tname\"/" file1.sas > file2.sas
```

btw, if you're going to be editing a file (that is if *file2.sas* is a temporary file), you should be using `ed` instead.

Comment: it has come up so many times on S.O. that it should be banned to be answered again :P I think S.O. should prevent a question to be posted, if it finds a similar topic, well, not prevent, but warn before posting that an alike-question is already answered, and have the users check that first before proceeding to post their question.

Comment: Actually, my problem is a bit more complex and not fixed by simply changing ' to ", the edited question is above. I think the problem I'm facing is quite challenging and not the common query that comes up on SO regarding this.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, i just remplaced single quotes by the double ones:

```
for a in $(cat ext.cnf); do sed -n "/$a$/p" file1 >> file2; done
```

For now, it's working well...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when `$ct_fname` is substituted, `sed` sees extra `/` separators, so

```
sed "24s/.*/"$ct_tname"/" file1.sas > file2.sas
```

becomes

```
sed "24s/.*/"%let outputfile=/user/ct_ARGUMENT1.csv;"/" file1.sas > file2.sas
```

and you'll get a `sed` error because there are 5 `/` instead of the expected 3.

Instead, change your `sed` separators to an unused character like `|` or `:`, and either single or double quotes will work just fine:

```
sed '24s|.*|'$ct_tname'|' file1.sas > file2.sas
sed "24s|.*|"$ct_tname"|" file1.sas > file2.sas
```

Comment: Brilliant! This helped me when my input string was full of /. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Shell variables are not expanded inside single quotes. Try this instead:

```
sed "24s/.*/\"$ct_tname\"/" file1.sas > file2.sas
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double (`"`) quotes, with single (`'`) quotes the value of the variable doesn't get replaced. Since you have double quotes in your replacement text, you need to escape them:

```
sed "24s/.*/\"$ct_tname\"/" file1.sas > file2.sas
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers focus on the use of escaped double quotes in their examples.  Note that this is not always what you want :

```
$ FOO="auie"; echo foo123bar|sed "s/123/\"$FOO\"/"
foo"auie"bar
$ FOO="auie"; echo foo123bar|sed "s/123/$FOO/"
fooauiebar
$ FOO="auie"; echo fooauiebar|sed "s/\"$FOO\"/123/"
fooauiebar
$ FOO="auie"; echo fooauiebar|sed "s/$FOO/123/"
foo123bar
```