# SH - Replace text

Tags: sed, replace, sh

I want to replace one string with another but I can't. The code is:

```
updatedb
MCRYPTINI=$(locate mcrypt.ini | grep 'apache2')
MCRYPTSO=$(locate mcrypt.so | grep "/mcrypt.so")

OLD="extension=mcrypt.so"
NEW="extension=$MCRYPTSO"

echo $MCRYPTINI
echo $MCRYPTSO
echo $OLD
echo $NEW
echo "'s/$OLD/$NEW' $MCRYPTINI"

sed -i 's/$OLD/$NEW' $MCRYPTINI
```

And the result is:

```
sudo sh testScript.sh
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so
's/extension=mcrypt.so/extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so' /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command
```

For the response I don't need to use 'sed', but it's looks easy and good.
I use sh not bash because I want the code can use in all the systems, so I prefer answers that follow that principle

UPDATE

```
sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/" $MCRYPTINI
```

error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: Have you already tried adding a `/` after `$NEW` in `sed` expression?

Comment: Ok, that's resolved the problem... But the string didn't change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a variable in a sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146098/use-a-variable-in-a-sed-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution could be:

```
sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/" $MCRYPTINI
```

but `$NEW` is a path, so I need to change "/" by other character, for example "+"

```
sed -i "s+$OLD+$NEW+" $MCRYPTINI
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a slash and double quotes:

```
sed -i  "s/$OLD/$NEW/" file
```

Comment: The last slash is correct, but with double quotes--> sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @oootramas : The last slash was missing in your snippet. And the double quotes also to be added.